# How do I output multiple rows of a user into an HTML table?

Tags: php, mysql

Based on my previous question about how to fetch rows from database. I was able to fetch what I needed in an array firm but then I need to echo each row in string using implode but I get an error. This is my code below to make you understand what I mean

```
      <?php
      $id = $_SESSION['login'];
                    $sqlB = 
      "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE id=? ORDER BY No  DESC LIMIT 10";
      $stmtB = $connection->prepare($sqlB); 
     $stmtB->bind_param('i', $id);
     $stmtB->execute();
     $resultB = $stmtB->get_result();

     $rowB = $resultB->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //print_r($rowB); 
    (Checking for the result in array) And it displayed all I needed perfectly.

    //now tried to  convert to string but I still get error of **array to string conversion.

    echo implode(" ",$rowB);
   exit; 
   ?>
```

Let's assume this is my table

```
Name                Amount             Gender
Stone Cold.         1245                Male
Kingsley.           500                 Male.
Stone Cold          2367                Male
Stone Cold.         5678.               Male
```

Now I want to print stone cold rows. Which is row 1,3 and 4 just exactly the same format with he above table. How do I get to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_all()` returns a 2-dimensional array. `implode()` requires the array to be 1-dimensional. You're getting the error because each element of the array is a nested array, and they can't be concatenated.

You should loop over the result set, imploding each row separately.

```
foreach ($rowB as $row) {
    echo implode(' ', $row) . "<br>";
}
```

To create an HTML table with the results, do:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($rowB as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $column) {
        echo "<td>$column</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```